# How to make return in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

Hi i have a very difficult question. I wrote a function in x64 assembly and then i wanted to use it in my main.c. I included the assembly function via header file. 
main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myunistd.h"
#include "mystddef.h"


int main(){

mywrite(1, "Test", 4);

}
```

myunistd.h:

```
#ifndef MYUNISTD_H
#define MYUNISTD_H

struct myrusage {};
ssize_t spastwrite(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);

#endif
```

myunistd.s:

```
global mywrite

section .text

mywrite:
  mov r8, rdi       ; parameters in registers only for testing
  mov r9, rsi
  mov r10, rdx
  mov rax, 1            ; write(
  mov rdi, r8           ;   STDOUT_FILENO,
  mov rsi, r9       ;   String,
  mov rdx, r10      ;   sizeof String
  syscall               ; );

  mov rax, 60           ; exit(
  mov rdi, 0            ;   EXIT_SUCCESS
  syscall               ; );
```

The function works but i have no return argument like in the original write syscall. Also have the warning "implicit declaration of function 'mywrite' is invalid in C99". 
Also good to know for you i defined size_t as unsigned long in mystddef.h. 
I dont know. Hope you can help :)

Compiled with:nasm -f elf64 myunistd.s -o myunistd.o
clang main.c myunistd.o -o exe

Thx

Comment: Since your function invokes `exit()` you have no chance of returning a value. Remove that block and simply use a `ret`. Your implicit declaration error is due to fact that you declared `spastwrite` and not `mywrite`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `exit` syscall, use `ret`:

```
global mywrite

section .text

mywrite:
  mov r8, rdi       ; parameters in registers only for testing
  mov r9, rsi
  mov r10, rdx
  mov rax, 1            ; write(
  mov rdi, r8           ;   STDOUT_FILENO,
  mov rsi, r9       ;   String,
  mov rdx, r10      ;   sizeof String
  syscall               ; );
  ret
```

In your `myunistd.h`, you're declaring `spastwrite` and not `mywrite`. Change this:

```
ssize_t spastwrite(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

to this:

```
ssize_t mywrite(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

and it will work.